# How to remove first line in JTextPane and setting setContentType("text/html")

Tags: java, jtextpane

I want to remove the first line in JTextPane and setting setContentType("text/html"); to be able to use html tags in JTextPane.

When I use this code

setContentType("text/html");

```
try {
  Element root = getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
  Element firstLine = root.getElement(0);
  getDocument().remove(firstLine.getStartOffset(), firstLine.getEndOffset());
   }
catch (Exception e) {e.toString();}
```

I get an exception

```
javax.swing.text.BadLocationException: Invalid remove
```

if I commented setContentType("text/html"); I can be able to remove the first line from JTextPane.

Answer (score 1):

For the HTMLEditorKit the `Element firstLine = root.getElement(0);` normally returns `<HEAD>` but you need `<BODY>`. Go through the Element Tree, find the BODY and remove the first child of BODY.

UPDATE:
The link shows a tool you can use to understand your Document structure.
http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneStructureTool.html

You can check which elements you have and figure out which exactly element should be removed.